# Crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) when using CharacterSet isSuperset

Tags: swift, nscharacterset

Trying to determine if an input string is a valid phone number using `CharacterSet`. Seems that `isSubset` works fine, but `isSuperset` will crash.

I think this is a bug in Foundation.

```
let phoneNumberCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "01234567890,;*+#").union(CharacterSet.whitespaces)
let zeroCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0")

if zeroCharacterSet.isSubset(of: phoneNumberCharacterSet) {
    print("zero is a subset of the phone number set")
}

if phoneNumberCharacterSet.isSuperset(of: zeroCharacterSet) {
    // will never get here due to crash
    print("is a superset of '0'")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63262)

> Seems the current bridging of `CharacterSet` generates something weird
>   which does not work with `isSuperset(of:)`. (It internally calls
>   `CFCharacterSetIsSupersetOfSet(_:_:)`.)

You can get

```
if phoneNumberCharacterSet.isSuperset(of: zeroCharacterSet) {
    // will never get here due to crash
    print("is a superset of '0'")
}
```

replaced by

```
let zeroString = "0"
if zeroString.rangeOfCharacter(from: phoneNumberCharacterSet.inverted) == nil {
    print("is a superset of '0'")
}
```